# Dimension of a subspace of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I saw this question in a textbook. I am facing difficulty in solving it.

Let $V$ be the vector space of all real polynomials and $W$ be the subspace generated by $$a x^2+b x+c$$ where $a,b,c$ take the values $(1,1,2),(1,2,5),(5,3,4)$ and $ (2,2,4)$ giving four quadratic polynomials.

The question asks for finding the dimension of $W$.

Comment: What is the dimension of the subspace spanned by the 4 vectors you have? (Also, do learn a little MathJax so folks can read your question.)

Comment: Can i find some online tutorials for Mathjax

Comment: This might help: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Find the largest subset of linearly independant vectors among
$$ \vec{a}=(1,1,2),\quad \vec{b}=(1,2,5),\quad \vec{c}=(5,3,4)\quad \text{and}\quad \vec{d}=(2,2,4).$$
Two things are obvious: (1) $\vec{d}=2\vec{a}$ and (2) $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are linearly
independent.

Answer (score 0):

Define $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3 \to V$ by $\phi(p)(x) = p_1+p_2x+p_3 x^2$. It is easy to see that $\phi$ is injective, hence the vectors $v_k \in \mathbb{R}^3$ are linearly independent **iff** the vectors $\phi(v_k)$ are.

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the subspace generated by the four vectors in the question.  From the above remark, we see that $\dim S = \dim \phi(S)$, and so we can concentrate on determining $\dim S$.

Let the vectors in the question be $v_1,...,v_4$. It is easy to see that $v_4 = 2 v_1$ so, we can discard $v_4$.

A little work shows that $v_3 = 7 v_1 - 2 v_2$, and that $v_1,v_2$ are not collinear, hence linearly independent. Hence
$S = \operatorname{sp} \{ v_1,v_2 \}$ and so $\dim S = 2$.